# Position cells within view and copy functions/formulas from existing cells in Libre Calc?

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I would like to keep a specific range of rows visible in Libre Calc. As new rows of data are entered, I would like the sheet/page to scroll, keeping the current row visible. As a comment made me realize: the issue isn’t so much just scrolling but ensuring newly entered cells use formulas from previous rows -- I’d like to have formulas/functions copied to a new row when it is used. This is a time keeping spreadsheet.

I am not asking for the freeze functionality to prevent the top few rows from scrolling.

The cell data are:

- A1 a date cell
- B1-G1 are time/description fields with functions calculating hours, etc.

Ideally, purely for aesthetic reasons, I’d like to determine when An-1 date is different than An and place row An at the top.  Primarly, I'm trying to ensure Calc copies the functions/formulas being used into a new row when started.

Does Libre Calc have a mechanism to position cells and formulas/functions from other cells?

Comment: Can there be enough rows of the new date that you would need to freeze the date n-1 row to keep it visible?  Other than that, you are just talking about keeping a date n-1 row at the top while new entries populate down the screen?

Comment: I currently have the column headings frozen.  I'd like the data to all scroll.  I don't actually mind if the row which starts a given date is at the top or not -- only for aesthetic reasons.  I realized the issue is more with copying formulas in cells than scrolling rows.  question edited ...